# Prove that a $k$-degenerate graph is ($k+1$)-colorable

Tags: graph-theory, induction, coloring

A graph is $k$-degenerate if every induced subgraph contains a vertex of degree at most $k$. How can I prove that a $k$-degenerate graph is ($k+1$)-colorable?

Answer (score 6):

*Hints:* If $G$ is the given $k$-degenerate graph, notice that $G$ is an induced subgraph of itself and so $G$ has a vertex $v$ of degree at most $k$.

> Why is $G-v$ also $k$-degenerate?

Now apply induction on the number of vertices to colour $G- v$ with $k+1$ colours.

> Can you now colour $v$ with one of the $k+1$ colours to obtain a proper $k+1$-colouring of $G$?

Comment: Because $G$ is $k$-degenerate we can say $G-v$ is also $k$-degenerate. So $G-v$ needs $k+1$ colors and adding $v$ now we need the same $k+1$ colors because $deg(v) \leq k$. Am i right?

Comment: To conclude that $G-v$ is $k$-degenerate, you need to verify the definition. Notice that an induced subgraph of $G-v$ is also an induced subgraph of $G$. For the second part, $G-v$ doesn't necessarily *need* $k+1$ colours. You just can assume by induction that $k+1$ colours *are enough*. So take any colouring of $G-v$ using at most $k+1$ colours. Since $\deg(v)\leq k$, do you definitely have an available colour that you can use to properly colour $v$?

Comment: yeah right $G-v$ needs atmost  $k$ +1 colors. Yes as the $deg(v) \leq k$ even if $deg(v) = k$ we have atleast one color left. Thanks